# Using Framer Motion in NextJS13 for page transitions

Tags: next.js, next.js13, framer-motion

Im using NextJS 13 with App Dir.
I have framer motion installed and am trying to implement fade out/fade in page transitions but after many many hours trying to get this to work I am officially stuck!

The main problem I face is that upon changing route the new page content seems to load before the exit (fade out) animation fires, this results in a brief glimpse of the new page content before it fades out and then in again.
Obviously what I'm trying to achieve here is when I click on a  element the page content will fade out, the route will change and then the content of the new page will fade in.

I can provide my code here but I have also created a code sandbox link which illustrates my issue: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/awesome-wiles-9vmdyx

```
// PageTransition.js
"use client"
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from "framer-motion";

const variants = {
  hidden: { opacity: 0 },
  enter: { opacity: 1, transition: { duration: 0.4 } },
  exit: { opacity: 0, transition: { duration: 0.4 } },
};

export default function PageTransition({ children, path }) {
  return (
    <AnimatePresence mode='wait'>
      <motion.div
        key={path}
        variants={variants}
        initial="hidden"
        animate="enter"
        exit="exit"
      >
        {children}
      </motion.div>
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
}

// layout.js
"use client"
import "./styles/globals.scss";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import localFont from "next/font/local";
import Header from "./components/common/Header";
import Footer from "./components/common/Footer";
import PageTransition from "./components/animate/PageTransition";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

const fedraSerif = localFont({
  src: "./fonts/FedraSerifAPro-Bold.ttf",
  display: "swap",
  variable: "--font-fedraSerif",
});

const fsMe = localFont({
  src: "./fonts/FS Me-Regular.otf",
  display: "swap",
  variable: "--font-fsMe",
});

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  const activePath = usePathname();
  return (
    <html lang="en" className={`${fedraSerif.variable} ${fsMe.variable}`}>
      <body>
        <Header />
        <PageTransition path={activePath}>
          {children}
        </PageTransition>
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Can anybody help here?
TIA

Answer (score -1):

You can make the component show smoothly, as follows.

Add a class .page-transition and style it:

```
.page-transition {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

In the component that should disappear smoothly, we add the `usePageTransition`:

```
export const usePageTransition = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll(".page-transition").forEach((item) => {
   item.style.opacity = 1;
  });
};
```

Home:

```
"use client";

import Image from "next/image";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { usePageTransition } from "./hooks/usePageTransition";

export default function Home() {
  useEffect(() => {
    usePageTransition();
  }, []);
  return (
    <main className="home page-transition">
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
      <Image src="/man.png" width={500} height={500} />
    </main>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/showpagetransitionnext13-m5n2wt

Comment: This doesn't use `framer-motion` so its not addressing the question. Also think this would be cleaner if it created a style object in state with the transition and default opacity 0 and just flip the opacity to 1 in the `useEffect` and pass style to the main element.